# Nginx works automatically for www, even without configuration

Tags: nginx

Without any configuration on my part, nginx serves website for www. as well as the domain I set in `server_name`. I have no idea how this is happening, but I'd like to disable this.

Meaning: I've configured a server for `subdomain.example.com`, that works fine, however `www.subdomain.example.com` also works!

This is my nginx conf:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

And then an example file from `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://656.655.665.655:3277;

    }

}
```

I've checked and I've got no wildcards in any of the other configs.

When I add:

```
server {
  server_name www.subdomain.example.com;
  return 301 $scheme://subdomain.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

That works, and www. is redirected, but I don't like that solution, for various reasons I'd like to simply just disable the www. completely.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's likely your browser is doing this, as I believe there was some change to both chrome and firefox to 'ignore' the www. appended to a URL. I personally think it's a dumb idea but alas. Try doing a dns lookup for both of the urls, with and without the www. The one without should fail unless you've got a wildcard. If it does fail, it's clearly the browser interfering.

Comment: @djsmiley2k I don't think that's it. I've tried using `curl` and still goes through, without any mention of www in nginx config

Answer (score 0):

This [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30240319/165358)
suggests using this code to remove `www` before any domain:

```
if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*)$) {
    rewrite / $scheme://$1 permanent;
}
```

Note that
[If Is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/),
but is said to work with `rewrite`.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question though, I even mentioned that when I do the redirect it redirects correctly, I would like to disable the www.subdomain.example.com completely, but nginx just somehow makes it work, which is weird since I did not explicitly say anywhere that www.subdomain.example.com should do anything.

Yes, if is evil, that's why I'm not using it in the redirect example...